# Is it possible to add multiple accounts to a twitter app? (Twitter API Bot)

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

i am trying to create some sort of twitter bot using the twitter api and tweepy.

I created an application at apps.twitter.com and generated the tokens to use the api for this account. Via a simple python script and tweepy i was able to create tweets automaticly, exactly what i wanted to do.

```
consumer_key = "abc..."
consumer_secret = "abc..."

access_token = "abc..."
access_token_secret = "abc..."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status("Nice!")
```

Now i wonder if i can "add" a second account to this twitter app with a different consumer Key and controll both accounts with my script.
I am new to all of this so i may miss something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i finally managed to bind multiple twitter accounts to a single twitter app!
after reading the docs at http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html i was able to create a simple script that allowed me to do exactly that:

```
import tweepy

consumer_token = "dsfg..."
consumer_secret = "LJdgfh..."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)

try:
    redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print("Error! Failed to get request token.")

print(redirect_url)

verifier = input('Verifier:')

try:
    auth.get_access_token(verifier)
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print("Error! Failed to get access token.")

new_token = auth.access_token
new_secret = auth.access_token_secret
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just modify your script to be more modular, create a function to handle this for example you could do something like this:

```
def handleTweets(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret):

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status("Nice!")
```

I would recommend maybe creating a config.py that has all your keys, you could create a list containing your consumers keys / access token associations and handle all in one place, then loop through each key and call the function.

Comment: with this solution i have to create an app for every account (with mobile number acticated) to get it to work like this but i want to use one app with multiple accounts

Comment: if this is possible was my real question, sorry if didn askt it right

Comment: You could have the same consumer_key and consumer_secret for both accounts, basically the access token and secret will be the ones that changed. So yes one app multiple accounts should work just fine.

Comment: exactly what i thought yesterday. Is there anyway where we can execute a script like `post_tweet.py` with parameters containing parameters such as `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`,`access_token`,`access_token_secret` ?